# Convert to date when different formats in the same column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I came across a column that contains dates (stored as text) in 2 different formats. Using to_date() requires to specify the format so it will only work with some of them.

Is there a way to convert both formats in parallel with a SELECT ?

```
        created_at         |   id
---------------------------+---------
 2015-08-27 04:59:40 -0400 | 9993833
 2015-08-27T03:40:07+12:00 | 9984557
 2015-08-26 03:04:35 -0400 | 9980626
 2015-08-26T13:11:51+12:00 | 9978784
 2015-08-26T06:18:04+12:00 | 9974751
 2015-08-25 00:21:47 -0400 | 9965448
 2015-08-24T15:01:09+12:00 | 9952732
 2015-08-23 22:47:32 -0400 | 9952671
 2015-08-24T12:49:57+12:00 | 9952099
 2015-08-24T12:04:04+12:00 | 9951839
 2015-08-23T17:49:24+12:00 | 9948236
 2015-08-23T11:37:53+12:00 | 9947015
 2015-08-21 03:13:16 -0400 | 9934367
 2015-08-21T18:36:18+12:00 | 9934148
 2015-08-21T17:23:30+12:00 | 9933522
 2015-08-21T15:33:50+12:00 | 9932949
 2015-08-20 12:06:37 -0400 | 9927425
 2015-08-21T03:16:58+12:00 | 9926932
```

Comment: It would be possible using a CASE...WHEN construct, provided postgresql supports it.

Comment: What do you want, just the date part or the whole timestamp?

Comment: These formats are not so different, postgresql can automatically identfy them, just cast them to `timestamp with time zone`, f.ex. `select created_at::timestamptz`.

Comment: @pozs This sir was the clean and simple solution I was hoping to find by posting this issue on SO. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**(Assuming that there are only 2 different types of date formats )** 
Handle the Two formats separately and combine using a UNION ALL.

```
select to_date(created_at,'format_specifier1')  as created_at , id from table 
where created_at NOT Like '%T%'

UNION ALL

select to_date(created_at,'format_specifier2')  as created_at , id from table 
where created_at Like '%T%'
```

so all you need to figure out is the 2 format specifier strings. (I don't have access to a postgre DB right now )